# Homotopy chat room

Tags: discussion

I started an MO homotopy theory chat room at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9418/homotopy-theory at the request of Jon Beardsley. there seem to be people in it already who know what the word "homotopy" means, so that is a good start. For now, i am the room owner, but we can fix that over time, once Jon gets his identities properly merged..

EDITTT: Jon's original room is now MO, which is more than I accomplished, go to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9417/homotopy-theory

Thursday morning: If you leave Meta and return, Jon's room is now visible on the middle right.

Comment: Why on SciComp and not MO?

Comment: @Manish, it is not on MO?

Comment: Well, there are some problems, but the kids are enjoying it.

Comment: @Manishearth How does one merge their accounts?

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks!

Comment: @SeanTilson http://mathoverflow.net/contact/user-merge

Comment: @Manishearth: That didn't work. I am in touch with them though.

Comment: @Manishearth, thanks for merging the rooms.

Comment: Well this turned out pretty well.

Comment: @JonBeardsley, just looked at it because of your comment, seems to have plenty of activity. My next project is to get the volunteers at the Berkeley city animal shelter to start a question/answer feature on their Facebook page on, for instance, the various tricky aspects of walking and training dogs.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, I don't really want to take credit for this thing.  I don't really think that I have the street-cred to create a homotopy theory chat room...

But it's super cool, and hopefully we can further cultivate the culture of creative exchange and conversation that's already grown around MO.

Comment: Is street cred hyphenated?

Comment: @Will: In Jon's answer yes; in your comment no.

Comment: @Asaf, that's some kind of Zen thing, right? Maybe Kaballah? Meanwhile, it shows people have Choice.

Comment: @Will: I don't know about that, but it beats grading homework.

Comment: So does chatting.

Comment: Jon, grading homework beats chatting about homotopy! ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, you must be crazy. lol

Comment: Well, I am a set theorist that work without the axiom of choice...

Comment: @AsafKaragila okay then. That settles it.  By the way, I'm a homotopy theorist, and I sort of have to use the Axiom of Choice, but I don't really believe in it.

Comment: Platonists always baffled me. For that matter, any sort of theism (even mathematical one) confuses me. What does belief have to do with anything? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Also, allow me to say, one thing we'd really like to do is get experienced mathematicians to if not lead, at least participate in, discussions regarding their research. I think it's really cool that some well respected and brilliant mathematicians are active on MO, and I think it'd be even cooler if we could arrange for them to come to the chat room and just chat about some particular subject for an hour or two.

Comment: I posted this on Giggle+ with a jpeg of the chat room,

Comment: @Will: Teehee??

Comment: @Asaf, well the repeat root canal went well, best available outcome, I'm still annoyed at having to go through it, and pay for it. That's life.