# Specialized chat rooms

Tags: discussion, chat

Would there be an interest in having more specialized chat rooms, like the one for homotopy theory that currently exists?

So far, the homotopy theory one seems to be fairly successful, and it seems that other topics might also enjoy a chat room like it.

Obviously, if such a chat room is to be useful, it will need to have at least a few experts interested in frequenting it, which would then mean that people should be at least somewhat sparing with pings.

I am posting this both as a general question about whether people would be interested in such chat rooms, and as a place where people can plan such chat rooms.

If you have a topic you would like a chat room for, put it as an answer. Upvotes for that answer should then be interpreted as someone saying "yes, I would use such a chat room to at least some extend" (preferably with a comment so it can be gauged who those people who are interested are).

Comment: I will add a link to a similar (at least to some extent) post on [math.meta.se]: [List of chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26814).

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that there is a separate discussion here on meta related to the Homotopy Theory chat room: [Homotopy chat room](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/221).

Answer (score 5):

July 3:
Well, it is gone now; it is worth starting a chat room and just chatting with random strangers, until such time as people interested in that topic begin to post there. Jon started a Homotopy chat room. It turned out not to have MO as a parent. So I started one, and Jon and I chatted, then some homotopy people. After a bit, it was revealed that my room was also not MO. So Manish merged the two rooms, mushed the posts together.

So, I think the thing to do is settle on a title, begin chatting in the new room with anyone at all on MO, and try to get graduate students involved, because they are sufficiently hyper to keep a room going. Should that work, look for postdocs and new assistant professors in or near the field. Online chat does seem to be a matter of taste. The relatively stable configuration is one or two established people peering in when they have time and are in the right mood, answering questions. Time will tell whether it is possible to hold scheduled sessions with larger numbers of people peering in, informal seminar. Jon is trying something along those lines, so maybe we will be seeing that in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit backwards to post here after creating the room, but well:

I created a specialised room though not in a math sense, but for questions related to editing, tagging and so on; it is called [MO editors' lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/mo-editors-lounge).

Comment: So if now one person joins the room it will be empty :-)

Answer (score 4):

Some friends and I wanted a chat room based on geometry and QFT (and also whenever topology, representation theory, ... comes in). I've gone ahead and created it: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82100/geometryphysics. If you're interested, feel free to stop by!

Comment: The room has bee [frozen for inactivity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/82100/2020/9/6). If there is interest to discuss topics in that room again, any moderator can unfreeze it. (In fact, it can be a moderator from any site, no necessarily MathOverflow moderator. I have mentioned basic advice on unfreezing [also in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/82100/2020/8/22).)

Answer (score 3):

I'd really like to see a category theory chatroom.  This would obviously have significant overlap with the homotopy theory chatroom, and could potentially detract from both, I don't know.  But pure category theory (and this could include $\infty$-category stuff, to try and steal some of the n-labbers away maybe) is pretty lovely.

Answer (score 3):

I think that adding a list of past chatrooms which are now [frozen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) but have been active at least for some time might be a useful addition to this question.

If somebody considers creating a new chat room, looking at an older room with similar topic might help to see how much interest was in discussing that particular area in chat at that time. And additionally if somebody wants to start a room on the same topic, they might [unfreeze the older room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room) instead of starting from the scratch if they consider it for some reason better. (E.g., if the older room contains some interesting conversations, they would be more visible.)

I added the rooms I am aware of and made this post community wiki. Feel free to update the list of rooms.

- There were two incarnations of room for algebraic geometry. [This one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9755/algebraic-geometry) had not much activity apart from the first few days. [The other one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/23540/algebraic-geometry) seem to have generated more activity. (I would say that for the first 6 to 8 months that the activity was not entirely negligible. It is the same room that was mentioned in this post on meta: [Algebraic Geometry Chat Room](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2250).) I will also add link to [Jon Beardsley's advice](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12179692#12179692) on what can help to make a room active - which was posted in one algebraic geometry rooms.
- A room for discussions about representation theory [was suggested by Tobias Kildetoft](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/355/specialized-chat-rooms/356#356) and he indeed [created such a room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9560/2013/7/8) although it never generated too much activity.
- [Homotopy Theory chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9417) was rather active for a long time, but eventually [it was frozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9417) after the activity decreased. As [mentioned by Jonathan Beardsley](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9417/2022/9/19), people who used to be active there moved to a [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord) server. Some [messages in the room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9417?m=58962906#58962906) and the [room topic](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9417?m=57753677#57753677) contain link to https://nodorek.net.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to have a chat room for representation theory (though possibly "algebraic representation theory" would be more precisely the subject I mean when I say representation theory).

Comment: It might be more effective to just start a room, and inhabit it for a while.  If one doesn't have enough reputation to start a room, answer or ask enough questions in that area until one does.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger An unused chat room with just 1 person in it will not seem attractive to most people, so it will not in itself make people start using it. That is why I made this thread.

Comment: Indeed.  So when you make it, start using it.  People will then get a good idea from the existing transcript if they want to contribute, but people are more likely to join/contribute if there is an existing room as well as a (non-meta) question and comment pointing to the room.

Comment: Room created and an initial question/topic for discussion posted. Come one come all!

Answer (score 1):

I want to start chat room/reading room for

- differential geometry as in first two chapters of Kobayashi and Nomizu.
- Stacks as in [Angelo Vistoli’s notes](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf) (also available [on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412512)).

Is there any one interested for the same?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see a chatroom that deals with group theory and group theoretic approaches to geometry. I know that geometry isn't a really fashionable subject right now, but I would like to talk to people who are interested in it.

Comment: I don’t know what geometry you are talking about.. can you tell something more..

Comment: Not too long ago a [Group Theory chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/80888/group-theory) was created on Mathematics site - although so far it has not generated much activity.