# Algebraic Geometry Chat Room

Tags: discussion, chat

At the request of Denis Nardin, I have started an MO algebraic geometry chat room at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23540/algebraic-geometry.  For now I am the room owner, but I am happy to let Denis own the room instead.

Comment: I do not think I am the right person to own an Algebraic Geometry chatroom. To begin with I am not an algebraic geometer.

Comment: @DenisNardin The only reason why I suggested this was because you had put forward the idea to me in the first place. I can remove that from my post above.

Comment: There is also a [dedicated thread](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/355/specialized-chat-rooms) for basically this type of information